# Using a shell script to interact with programs

Tags: linux, shell, ftp

I need to upload a file via FTP with shell script.
Can I interact with FTP from the script? My Script is at http://pastebin.com/A76fsaM3

```
cd MyLocalUploadDir
ftp
open ftp.server.com
myusername
mypassword
put LocalIteam.TXT
```

Will this work? Is there another way to interact with FTP from within a shell script? Any help is appreciated!

See http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/FTP-3.html for information regarding interaction with FTP.

Comment: Thanks for inserting code. My tab key is broken.

Comment: `tab` in a html-textbox? use 4 `spaces`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a here-doc. Otherwise, the lines after `ftp` will not be used as input to the program.

```
cd MyLocalUploadDir
ftp <<EOF
open ftp.server.com
myusername
mypassword
put LocalIteam.TXT
quit
EOF
```

You can also avoid putting your username and password in the script by using a `.netrc` file.

And instead of using the `ftp` program, you could use `curl` to do it in one line.

```
curl --upload-file MyLocalUploadDir/LocalIteam.TXT 'ftp://myusername:mypassword@ftp.server.com/'
```

You can also use the `--netrc` option to `curl` to tell it to get the username and password from the `.netrc` file.